# Finding MAX value for a certain month

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a problem that shouldn't be a problem but I'm unable to solve it.

My data looks like this:

```
2012-04-05     1280
2012-04-17     1340
2012-04-20     1510
2012-05-03     1670
2012-05-09     1880
```

What I want to do is to find the MAX value for april and for may.

So MAX for april should return 1510 and MAX for may should return 1880. Can this be done?

EDIT:
Maybe simplified it a bit too much, here is an example closer to what I really want to do:

```
2012-04-04     14     220
2012-04-11    453     863
2012-04-19    900    1310
2012-05-02   1400    1810
2012-05-15   1900    2250
```

These are milage from my cars trip computer. I would like to calculate how far I drove each month.

```
For april: 1310-14 = 1296
For may: 2250-1400 = 850
```

Comment: What about the miles between 1310 and 1400 don't you want those allocated to one month or another?

Comment: Yes, all I want is to take the highest value from column C and subtract with the lowest value from column B within the date range (the month).

Answer (score 3):

A simple array formula can do this.  If your dates are formatted as dates in Excel, paste the following into a cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=MAX(IF(MONTH($A$1:$A$5)=4,B1:B5))
```

Can this be expanded to also allow 0 to be filtered out? When you use the MIN instead of MAX and your data range has empty values this results into 0 to be reported as the lowest value.

Answer (score 2):

A simple array formula can do this.  If your dates are formatted as dates in Excel, paste the following into a cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=MAX(IF(MONTH($A$1:$A$5)=4,B1:B5))
```

If your dates are formatted as text, paste the following into a cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=MAX(IF(MID($A$8:$A$12,6,2)="04",$B$8:$B$12))
```

Comment: This answer is good unless the data spans more than 12 consecutive months.  If so, you'd need a more complex expression to disambiguate, for example, May 2012 and May 2011.

Comment: Haha, thats so cool! It works! But if I want to take MAX value minus MIN value, can that be done? What I need to do is to take the max value and subtract the min value.

Comment: Just subtract the same expression with `MIN` instead of `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need the answer once, filter by month and run a max function.

Comment: I need this data on a "dashboard" I'm creating with some key values. By filtering, do you mean hiding months that are not interested or can I do it in a way like this: =FILTER(...) ?

Comment: if you want an updating dashboard you will need a different approach. i will look into it and edit if I find something

Comment: Ok, cool. With dashboard I just simply mean a summary with the max values for each month. Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pivot table.  Below, Amount is summarized by Max.  I right-clicked on the date column, chose Group By and then selected both Year and Month.  The picture obviously shows the source data, pivot table and two dialogs.  In practice you'd put the pivot table on its own worksheet:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's also an approach. haven't worked that much with pivot tables but I will have a look. It sort of messes up the look of my spreadsheet but that's a small problem. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple formula to get max of the month in a given range.
where J2 - J7 is my date range, use Max to get maximum of the dates in that range and use text to get the month.

```
=TEXT(MAX(J2:J7),"mmm")
```